# Can a function be both Schur-concave and Schur-convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, majorization

I know that any linear and symmetric function $f:\mathbb{R}^n_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ is both Schur-concave and Schur-convex. Let $f$ be also increasing and continuous, and suppose that $f$ is non-linear, can it still be both Schur-concave and Schur-convex?

Comment: What you meant to say is "Any linear, **symmetric** function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is both Schur-convex and Schur-concave." To see that symmetry is required consider $f(x):=x_1$ on $\mathbb R^n, n\geq 2$. While $e_1\prec e_n$ ($e_n\prec e_1$) one has $f(e_1)=1>0=f(e_n)$ so $f$ is not Schur-convex (not Schur-concave).

Comment: Absolutely! You are right, thanks for pointing it out. Should I edit myself or let you do it? (I'm not sure what is the usual way of doing here).

Comment: You're of course free to edit your question at any time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Short answer:* Indeed linearity is not required.

*Detailed answer:* Let $f$ be Schur-concave and Schur-convex (so in particular $f$ is symmetric), that is, for all vectors $x,y$ with $x\prec y$ one has $f(x)\leq f(y)\leq f(x)$, hence $f(x)=f(y)$. In particular $f$ has to be constant on each trace hyperplane $T_c:=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:\sum_{j=1}^n x_j=c\}$, $c\in\mathbb R$ because $m_c:=\frac{c}n(1,\ldots,1)^\top\prec x$ for all $x\in T_c$. In other words because all vectors can be related to each other via majorization (through the unique minimal vector $m_c$ w.r.t $\prec$) $f$ cannot distinguish between any of them.

This allows us to define an auxiliary map $\alpha:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ via $\alpha(c):=f(\frac{c}n(1,\ldots,1)^\top)$ to find
$$
\forall_{x\in\mathbb R^n}\quad f(x)=f\big(\tfrac{\sum_{j=1}^nx_j}n(1,\ldots,1)^\top\big)=\alpha\Big(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\Big)\,.\tag{1}
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$. In other words the only information $f$ can distill from the input is the sum of its entries.
And this is as far as we get; we know that $f$ has to of this form, and for **all** choices of $\alpha$ the function $f$ will be Schur-convex and Schur-concave (i.e. (1) is a characterization). Even adding the requirement that $f$ is continuous will not make $\alpha$ linear (only continuous), and for good reason:

> **Example.** The map $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto (x_1+x_2)^2$ (non-linear!) is Schur-convex and Schur-concave.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I do agree with your reasoning. However, as I see it, that the function  is a transformation of a linear function (the sum of the elements of ). So, indeed, a non-linear function can be both S-concave and S-convex but, if this is the case, do we necessarily have that this function is a transformation of a sum?  Your "the only information 
 can distill from the input is the sum of its entries" leads me to an affermative answer but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Indeed, equation (1) shows that $f$ has to be of the form $\alpha(\sum_jx_j)$. Thus every map that is Schur-convex and Schur-concave first maps $x$ to $\sum_jx_j$ (linear!) which is then input into an arbitrary real function $\alpha$

Comment: Very clear! Thanks a lot!